# How to request multiple fields in restful api mysql

Tags: mysql, rest

Im trying to filter in restful api. So right now I'm getting a lastname in my database field, what I want to try now is how to filter and get the field and what I should put in my api url

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[GET]` in your restfull API, then manage it in backend. 

Your URL could be in this format http://location/rest/apiName/?requestfield=LastName&query=Chan&responseField=BirthDate 

Your backend API should handle the parameters, `requestField` and `query` to search for the record and return the field using the `responseField` value

//Note:
OR you can also code your backend API to return a JSON format, and handle the field selection on the front-end

Answer (score 0):

You should not take filter parameters as path parameters that should be query parameters.

As may user want to search by only first name or last name or both and in that case your URL will be incorrect and API will throw 404.

so URL should be:

```
/api/customers/search
```

fetch the parameters like below:

```
$firstname = $request.query.firstname;
$lastname = $request.query.lastname;
```

Modify your query like this:

```
Select * from customers where last_name like '$lastname%' and first_name like '$first_name%'
```

I hope it helps you.